# MIT App Inventor - simplify code for SelectColor variable for 84 different buttons

Tags: android, app-inventor

I have already built a usable app using App Inventor. This is my FIRST go at this.
I am trying to make the code cleaner.

I made a checklist app for a game. It has 84 buttons that identify droppable items. The user click the button to change the button image, signifying they got the drop.

[Example of 1 Button's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEP4j.png) 
[image]

I simply copied this 84 times - yeah I know.
Can anyone help me create a procedure that says something like "for Buttons 1-84" do this? I'd much rather have one block of code doing this rather than 84. Let me know if you would like more screenshots?

Comment: see these examples [How to work with the advanced features](https://puravidaapps.com/checkbox.php) and [A Multiple Choice Quiz: How to work with the advanced features](https://puravidaapps.com/quiz.php)

Comment: A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles  
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .